# Run function each day at set time

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timespan

So I have an app that I need to run an email function each day at a time set.  So in this case I set it for 6PM.  I left it running and went home from work.  At 6PM I received the email so the function ran.  Well come midnight it ran again, and because it ran at midnight and that's technically today, it now won't run again until 6PM the next day instead of 6PM tonight since it already ran at midnight.  I can't figure out what's wrong and why it ran at midnight.

```
Private Target As DateTime
Private state As MaintenanceState = MaintenanceState.WaitingToStart
Public MaintenanceTime As New TimeSpan(Hour, Min, 0)
Private WaitingInterval As New TimeSpan(0, 5, 0) ' Five minutes

Private Enum MaintenanceState
    WaitingToStart
    Started
End Enum

Private Sub tmr_Maintenance_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmr_Maintenance.Tick
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = Target.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
    lblStatus.Text = ts.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
    If DateTime.Now >= Target Then
        tmr_Maintenance.Stop()
        Select Case state
            Case MaintenanceState.WaitingToStart
                SendEmail()
                state = MaintenanceState.Started
                Target = DateTime.Now.Add(WaitingInterval)
            Case MaintenanceState.Started
                If Done = 1 Then
                    Target = DateTime.Now.Add(WaitingInterval)
                Else
                    state = MaintenanceState.WaitingToStart
                    Target = GetNextMaintenanceTarget(MaintenanceTime)
                End If
        End Select
        tmr_Maintenance.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetNextMaintenanceTarget(ByVal time As TimeSpan) As DateTime
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(time)
    If DateTime.Now > dt Then
        dt = dt.AddDays(1)
    End If
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Save yourself alot of pain and just use [task scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) which does all the scheduling you need.

Comment: Your talking about the windows service correct?  To just run the application each day itself?  It may come to that I suppose.  I'd still like to figure out what went wrong here if only for my own learning experience.

Comment: yes it is run as a Windows service, and it's commonly used to run programs at specific intervals.

Comment: If `MaintenanceTime` somehow got passed into `GetNextMaintenanceTarget` as `(0, 0, 0)` it would explain the midnight run but it is a bit difficult to tell what happened without knowing what the `MaintenanceTime` value is.

Comment: @OSKM `MaintenanceTime` was set to `18:00` so it would run at 6PM each day.  Which it did.  But then it ran at `24:00` as well.  No way `(0,0,0)` could have be passed that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest removing all code to do with scheduling and instead schedule the executable to run using Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

A possibly slightly easier way of achieving what you want would be:

Leave the `Timer` `Interval` set as the default 100.

```
Private Sub tmr_Maintenance_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmr_Maintenance.Tick
    tmr_Maintenance.Stop()
    If tmr_Maintenance.Interval = 86400000 Then
        'timer has hit daily run time, run daily code
        SendEmail()

    ElseIf tmr_Maintenance.Interval = 100 Then
        'set interval to next daily run time
        Dim timetillruntime As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 18, 0, 0), Now()) * 1000
        tmr_Maintenance.Interval = timetillruntime

    Else
        'time has hit daily runtime on first day, set timer interval to 24 hours
        tmr_Maintenance.Interval = 86400000
        'run daily code
        SendEmail()

    End If
    tmr_Maintenance.Start()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

Hope this snippet helps

```
Dim TimeOfBeep as Integer = 18 ' 24 hour format
Dim Target As DateTime = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, TimeOfBeep , 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    TextBox1.Text = Now
    TextBox2.Text = Target
    Dim TDiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Now, Target) / 60 / 60
    TextBox3.Text = TDiff  ' Time remains for next run

    If (TDiff <= 0) Then
        Beep()
        'sendmail()
        Target.AddHours(24)
    End If
End Sub
```

You can set timer1.interval = 1000 ms OR 60000  if you can tolerate to save some CPU Work...etc.

This code beeps once every day at specific hour,
as in question at 18:00:00:00

**Update:** This is a hint and not a solution, it is constructed to fit general need, you can adjust to fit your solution.